# Memcached: Can you start Memcached with `lru mode flat`?

Tags: configuration, memcached

- I wanted to experiment with using Memcached in the [`flat`](https://memcached.org/blog/modern-lru/) mode (as opposed to the default mode [`segmented`](https://memcached.org/blog/modern-lru/))
- Right now all I see in the documentation is a runtime command for switching modes: [`lru mode flat`](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/1.6.17/doc/protocol.txt#L1025)
- I run most of my stuff in Kubernetes with Helm charts and so if there is a way to specify the mode at the start that would make my life easier

#### Can you start Memcached with `lru mode flat`?

Answer (score 1):

##### In a nutshell, no

- I checked at all the `-h` options for memcached
- none of the options set the mode to `flat` like the runtime command `lru mode flat`

##### Workaround: wait for the process to start then execute the runtime command

- wait for the process to come online by polling via telnet somehow (use the `quit` or `stats` telnet command.)
- use telnet to execute the command `lru mode flat` then `quit` (`printf "lru mode flat\r\nquit\r\n" | telnetlib3-client ${HOSTNAME} ${PORT}`)

##### not as good workaround: turn off the `hot` and `warm` caches be similar to `flat` mode

This idea is from the `memcached/doc/protocol.txt` section `lru mode flat` where it says:

> If switching from segmented to flat mode, the background thread will pull items from HOT|WARM into COLD queue.

- at the start use command line argument `--extended hot_lru_pct=0,warm_lru_pct=0`
- the idea is to use the `--extended` options to set the equivalent of `lru tune 0 0 0.20 2.00` (current default is `lru tune 20 40 0.20 2.00` i think)

update: i tested this command line option and the above command line errors out because of the values. the `pct` fields require the value to be >= 1. `factor` fields require the values to be > 0.0.

- here is the new command line: `--extended hot_lru_pct=1,warm_lru_pct=1,hot_max_factor=0.0000000001,warm_max_factor=0.0000000001`
- this command does not: turn off the hot/warm caches or change the mode to `flat`
- this command does: tells memcached to always move hot and warm items to cold